# Is there a function to test literals in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I saw functions like `number?` and `string?`.

Is there a function to test if a form is a literal?

I mean all literals in Clojure.

This is what I am trying to do.

;; Abstract Syntax Representation

```
(defrecord VarExp [id])
(defrecord LiteralExp [datum])
(defrecord LambdaExp [ids body])
(defrecord IfExp [pred true-exp false-exp])
(defrecord AppExp [rator rands])

(defn parse-expression [datum]
  (cond
   (symbol? datum) (VarExp. datum)
   (literal? datum) (LiteralExp. datum)
   (list? datum) (cond
              (= (first datum) 'fn) (LambdaExp. (map parse-expression (second datum))
                                                (parse-expression (nth datum 2)))
              (= (first datum) 'if) (IfExp.
                                     (parse-expression (second datum))
                                     (parse-expression (nth datum 2))
                                     (parse-expression (last datum)))
              :else (AppExp.
                     (parse-expression (first datum))
                     (map parse-expression (rest datum))))
   :else (throw
           (Exception. (str 'parse-expression
                       ": Invalid concrete syntax " datum)))))
```

I'd like to parse S-exp to AST without using any standalone parser because s-exp is very much like a parse tree.

My current solution is:

```
(defn literal? [datum]
  (or
   (true? datum)
   (false? datum)
   (string? datum)
   (nil? datum)
   (symbol? datum)
   (number? datum)))
```

Is this already the most practical one?

BTW, this is the grammar of Clojure
literal
    : STRING
    | NUMBER 
    | CHARACTER
    | NIL
    | BOOLEAN
    | KEYWORD
    | SYMBOL
    | PARAM_NAME
    ;

STRING : '"' ( ~'"' | '\' '"' )* '"' ;

NUMBER : '-'? [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]+)? ([eE] '-'? [0-9]+)? ;

CHARACTER : '\' . ;

NIL : 'nil';

BOOLEAN : 'true' | 'false' ;

KEYWORD : ':' SYMBOL ;

SYMBOL: '.' | '/' | NAME ('/' NAME)? ;

PARAM_NAME: '%' (('1'..'9')('0'..'9')*)? ;

Comment: @noisesmith Really? I found it here(https://github.com/luckykevin/grammars-v4/blob/master/clojure/Clojure.g4#L26). What if I just want to detect those literals? Do I have to parse it using a parser?

Comment: See https://github.com/clojure/jvm.tools.analyzer for generating AST from syntax.

Comment: @luckykevin I realized I was wrong and deleted the comment, I had forgotten that clojure had two usages of the word "literal" in terms of input forms

Comment: @A.Webb I've looked at this tool. Seems it will evaluate each symbol. For example, '+' becomes 'clojure.core/add' which is definitely not what I want cuz I want to keep '+' as it is. Thx anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A literal is a `compile time` concept (i.e the parsing of literals to corresponding value/object is done by compiler), where as functions are `runtime concept` (i.e they work on values that are available at runtime) , so, no there is no such function possible as the function won't have any way to check if a value/object was a result of literal compilation. 
Only a macro can say if something is literal or not.

Comment: Actually, I would say that "literals" are concepts in the reader (when parsing strings into Clojure data forms), not the compiler (which takes those as inputs).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such function in Clojure.

There are many kinds of literals, including compound collections like maps, sets, vectors, lists, etc so I'm not sure that "literal?" would actually be a meaningful question.

Comment: Maybe it can be useful inside macros?

Comment: I mean all literals in Clojure.

Comment: @Alex Miller I think he means Literals in the sense of items under the heading "Literals" on the [doc page for the reader](http://clojure.org/reader). Strings, Numbers, Characters, nil, Boolean, Keywords.